# suppress repetition of entry in subentry with imakeidx

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690846/sort-index-entries-by-middle-name#690848) who assisted me in sorting index entries by middle name. Now I'd like the associated sub-entries not to repeat the text of the entry: thus the entry would read as

```
Gaius Julius Sneezer
    Hayfever, 1
    March, 1
```

Rather than repeating the entry each time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Index of Romans]

\newcommand\rindex[1]{\xrindex#1\relax}
\def\xrindex#1 #2 #3\relax{\index{#2 #1 #3@#1 #2 #3}}

\begin{document}
This is text. 
\rindex{Gaius Julius Sneezer!Hayfever}
\rindex{Gaius Julius Sneezer!March}
\rindex{Marcus Tullius Snifero!Allergies}
\rindex{Marcus Tullius Snifero!Dust}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I introduced a second command for the `!` cases, you could of course get more complicated and use a single command with some testing, but I'd keep it simple.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Index of Romans]

\newcommand\rrindex[1]{\xrrindex#1\relax}
\def\xrrindex#1 #2 #3!#4\relax{\index{#2 #1 #3@#1 #2 #3!#4}}

\begin{document}
This is text. 
\rrindex{Gaius Julius Sneezer!Hayfever}
\rrindex{Gaius Julius Sneezer!March}
\rrindex{Marcus Tullius Snifero!Allergies}
\rrindex{Marcus Tullius Snifero!Dust}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much (again!)